# React-Native LayoutAnimation not working on Android even with UIManager settings

Tags: javascript, animation, android-animation, react-native

I am trying to add a smooth animation when a user swipes out an element and removes it from a list.

It works fine on iOS but does not work on Android at all.

This is what I put in a constructor

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
       UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
       UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
  }
```

This is my code in remove method

```
  removeRecipient = ({ item: { id, received_vaults_count: vaults } }: Object, rowMap) => {
    if (!vaults) {
      rowMap[id].closeRow(); // close deleted row
      //show notification default duration 1 second
      notify(i18n.t('recipientsDashboard.shortDeleteNotification'));  
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
      this.props.removeById(id); // remove recipient by id from server
      return;
   }

   const DURATION = 3; // time in seconds
   notify(i18n.t('recipientsDashboard.longDeleteNotification'), DURATION);
   setTimeout(() => {
     rowMap[id].closeRow();
   }, 1000);
};
```

Does anyone meet this issue?

Comment: I have tried using a LayoutAnimation.spring()
It also does not work. Seems like its an issue, because I really do not get what am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 1):

Here is some of the code I used to get it to work.

**react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.3**

{    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

```
    if (UIManager) {
        return UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
}

componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
}}
```

Comment: if I want to add some durations?

Comment: @DevAS use this:
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
      ...LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut,
      duration: 250,
    });